# Move to next/prev marker keystroke not working in Blender 3.6.4

Tags: workflow, shortcut, marker

I just downloaded 3.6.4 and have discovered that Ctrl-Shift-[left arrow|right arrow] no longer moves the timeline between markers. Is this something other people have noted, and is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can still go into the *Marker panel > Jump to Previous Marker* and <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Assign Shortcut*:

[image]